# Is it possible to select these queries in 1 sql select?

Tags: mysql, sql

We have 2 select sql query:

```
SELECT id, username, group_id, score FROM users WHERE status=1 AND
active=1 AND id != 9 AND score >= 100 ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 2;
```

and

```
SELECT id, username, group_id, score FROM users WHERE status=1 AND
active=1 AND id != 9 AND score <= 100 ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 2;
```

How can select them by 1 sql query?

It is a MySQL database.

Comment: If you query once `score <= 100` and in the other query `score >=100` and you want to combine both querys, just remove the `AND score >=100` from the first query and your results are combined

Comment: @EdwinKrause No it is not, I need 2 users with score greater than specific score and 2 users less than it.

Comment: Please add the result you're looking for to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `union all` for that

```
(SELECT id, username, group_id, score FROM users WHERE status=1 AND
active=1 AND id != 9 AND score >= 100 ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 2)
union all
(SELECT id, username, group_id, score FROM users WHERE status=1 AND
active=1 AND id != 9 AND score <= 100 ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 2)
```

Comment: it says:  #1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Comment: Can you try `(SELECT id, username, group_id, score FROM users WHERE status=1 AND
active=1 AND id != 9 AND score >= 100 ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 2)
union all(
SELECT id, username, group_id, score FROM users WHERE status=1 AND
active=1 AND id != 9 AND score <= 100 ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 2)`